# How do I write a Java program that calculates the factors of a number?

Tags: java, factorization

I need help thinking up a formula for finding the factors of a number:

> Write a method named printFactors that accepts an integer as its
>   parameter and uses a fencepost loop to print the factors of that
>   number, separated by the word " and ". For example, the number 24's
>   factors should print as:
>
> ```
> 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 6 and 8 and 12 and 24
> ```
>
> You may assume that the number parameter's value is greater than 0.

Please don't give me a COMPLETE program as I would like to try it out myself.

The current code I have has a for loop to control the number of "and's" appearing, however, I printed out the last number by itself since I don't want a "24 and" attached to it...
So the output looks something like this at the moment:
"1 and 2 and 3" (I haven't yet thought up the equation hence the 1,2,3...)

I'm currently thinking that the factors requires a % kind of formula right? Will I need division? I was also thinking of printing out 1 and whatever the number (in this case, 24)  you are finding factors for, since 1 and the number itself are always factors of itself.
What else am I missing??

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Homework? If so tag it as "Homework"

Comment: You are very close, I suggest you think it out on your own and not ask here. Think of a for loop.

Comment: just test all prime numbers up until sqrt(n)...

Comment: @JeremyD: Wrong - that tag is obsolete

Comment: [homework tag is deprecated and discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/signaling-homework-questions-after-the-deprecation-of-the-homework-tag)

Comment: @Eric hmm I didn't know that. Sorry then.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys :) Next time, I will verify my information before telling anything ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - array list to output all factors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863500/java-array-list-to-output-all-factors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm currently thinking that the factors requires a % kind of formula right?

Yes.

> I was also thinking of printing out 1 and whatever the number (in this case, 24) you are finding factors for, since 1 and the number itself are always factors of itself.

If you test every number from 1 to n (e.g. from 1 to 24) then 1 and the number itself don't need to be special cases (because they'll simply satisfy your ordinary "% kind of formula").

Maybe 1 is a special case because it doesn't have the word "and" in front of it.

> What else am I missing??

This may be more complicated than you want, but to find all the factors of n you only need to loop up to the square root of n.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! that's all I needed :D